# C++ library for creating temporary files and directories, and their names

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, software-development, c++

I'm looking for a small C++ library (i.e. not Boost), which can do the following:

- Create a new unique single-path-element (file name, directory name) for use for a temporary file or directory
- Create either a new temporary file or directory, with and without a specified base path

Required features:

- Cross-platform: Supports at least Linux, Windows, MacOS.
- Small.
- Stable or actively-maintained.
- Requires at most C++11.
- LGPL/BSD/MIT or similar license.
- Gratis.

Desired features:

- Supports any Unix variant as well.
- Supports specifying some kind of template for the filename.
- Can use C++ features beyond C++11's, if available.

Motivation: I want to use this in some unit-testing code, and Boost is too big of a dependency. I'd like something small I could "vendor".

Comment: Pure C++ way for [tempfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022500/11621646) an [tempdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c/58454949#58454949)

Comment: 1. I want a library which does all of what I described above. 2. `tmpfile()` doesn't tell me what the name of the file is. 3. I don't like how tmpnam relies on the L_tempnam macro.